# Convert a silmple Mysql to JPQL Queries

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpql

Good Morning everyone, after lookin everwhere, i come to you to ask for a help.
So i have a this mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE WORPLACE ='TECHNICIAN',
```

And here is my JQPL query

```
SELECT U FROM USER U WHERE U.WORPLACE =:+TECHNICIAN
```

But some how i get this error on Glassfish

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument Technician not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.
```

Here is the code of my arraylist on the managed Bean

```
public List<Users> getListUsers() {
    return this.userService.getTechnicians("Technician");
}
```

So, what do i want specificlly. I want a query that can sort in a table list of user where there workplace are 'Technician'.

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: what is ":+TECHNICIAN" ? A named parameter is preceded by colon. But what is the + sign doing? Who knows what is in this "getTechnicians" method ...

Comment: sorry, getTechnicians is the the method whose call the query 'SELECT U FROM USER U WHERE U.WORPLACE =:+TECHNICIAN'   TECHNICIAN is the one my many workplaces whose is persed on the save method

Comment: Did you tried to remove the + sign on jpql query?

Comment: So post the code for that method

Comment: When i try to remove the '+' this send me a synthax error. public List<Userr> getTechnicians(String Technician) {
         return getEntityManager()                                   
                .createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.poste =:"+ Technician )
                .getResultList();
    } .Here is the complete query. this seem to be without error. But anyhow glassfish send me a java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument. Im so confuse

Answer (score 0):

In JPQL named query parameters start with a `:` followed by the name. So, if you want to call your query parameter `Technician` you need to reference it as `:Technician` in your query.

You can then call the `setParameter` method on the `Query` interface with the parameter name and its value.

Here's an example using your query:

```
public List<User> getTechnicians(String technician) { 
   TypedQuery<User> q = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.poste =:Technician", User.class );
   q.setParameter("Technician", technician);
   return q.getResultList(); 
}
```